# Objective-C Novice. Change property in Controller from another Controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iboutlet

The context: I have three views. One Introductory view, an Upload view and the Main view. As classes (With their respective headers) I have the rootViewController (SwitchViewController), IntroViewController and UploadViewController. The first view to be shown is IntroView. The user presses a button (declared in SwitchViewController) that takes them to the UploadView, then in the UploadView they get to choose an image and press the button again to go back to IntroView.

The thing is that while the user gets to pick the image with UIImagePickerController the button to switch views won't hide nor a UIImageView I have with a logo on top of the view(screen). The UIImageView and the UIButton are both declared in SwitchViewController's header.

The code used:

UploadViewController.h

```
#import [...] //Imports
@class SwitchViewController;
@interface UploadViewController : 
UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, 
UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate> {
    UITextField *imageTextField;
    UIImageView *uploadedImage;
    SwitchViewController *switchViewController;
[...]
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) SwitchViewController *switchViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *imageTextField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *uploadedImage;
[...]
@end
```

UploadViewController.m

```
[...]
- (IBAction) selectImageButtonPressed {
self.switchViewController.submitButton.hidden = YES;
self.switchViewController.imageLogo.hidden = YES;

[...] //continues
```

I just begun recently programming in objective-c so please forgive me if the question is very essential. I have looked and am following "Beginning iPhone 3 Development" of APRESS. But even if it helps to greatly understand the basics sometimes I get lost.

PS: If it is clearer to answer the question the SwitchViewController.h and .m snippet codes can be provided if asked. But I thought this text is big as it is.

Comment: You have linked the outlets in Interface Builder correctly, right?

Comment: Yes I did. I have checked a few times just to be sure...

Comment: @Joze can you provide the pics of the 3 views. its hard to understand your requirement. and if not than can you u make the question more simpler.

Comment: Oh. Right. Yeah I see why it's not working. You're trying to change properties of another view controller. You shouldn't do that. Just change the property in the viewWillDisappear of the method that's hiding and you'll have your problem solved.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do (change a property of another view controller). Because the method is the ImagePicker and is being used in the UploadView and not on SwitchView(rootController). To which viewWillDisappear are you referring to? In any case I need the button to only hide when the imagePicker comes up, not when the entire view is about to disappear. I'm not sure if I made myself clear. I'll try editing the question to make it clearer. And if I shouldn't do that then what is the alternative in this case?

Comment: How/where is `switchViewController` getting set? From what you've described, I'm guessing it's `nil` in `selectImageButtonPressed`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem after refactoring the whole code and changing the general structure of the program itself. Now I have 3 views and each with a viewController to control it. All the switching of views occurs in the Delegate since he has access to everyone. That way I can control every property with every controller, without much difficulty. Changing the property of one of the objects present in one view from another view is difficult and rather inconvenient if not sometimes impossible.

The approach I took when asking this question was short sighted for the application that had to be done. I thank all those who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

@Joze i think I may have understood your problem `switchViewController` is a variable of the class `UploadViewController` so if you do anything with that variable it wont affect the switchViewController view. so when you are calling the switchViewController view at that time you have to do `initWithNibName: bundle:` and then hide the button and imageView and also you need to do something like `switchViewController.delegate = self;` and then call the view modally or what ever way you want it.

PS. i m not sure the that spelling is correct. i dont have xcode at my home.
I hope your problem solves with this.

Comment: I actually did that at the viewDidLoad method of UploadViewController. Here is what I did I hope it is legible: SwitchViewController *switchController = [[SwitchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SwitchViewController" bundle:nil];
 self.switchViewController = switchController;
 [switchController release];
    [super viewDidLoad]; If it is not legible or you need more code let me know.

Comment: i dont mean that you need to do this in your view did load method. you need to do this when you are going to show the SwitchViewController. like when a button is pressed.

Comment: how are you calling the other view (SwitchViewController)

Comment: I'm sorry Robin I don't quite understand what you mean with how am I calling the other view. I also changed the code from the question (just changed the position where I hide the buttons not on the imagePicker but when I press the button to pick an image [then goes the image picker]) I just do self.switchViewController.submitButton.hidden = YES to call it. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Joze can you tell me, in which view or in which viewcontroller is the button and imageView

Comment: It is in SwitchViewController. { @interface SwitchViewController : UIViewController { UIButton *submitButton;
 UIImageView *imageLogo; }@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *submitButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageLogo; } The action for the button is also declared here as IntroViewController and UploadViewController.

Comment: how can you declare the action for a button present in SwitchViewController in other methods. Or i think i m not understanding your approach at all. so let me edit my answer.

Comment: That's the thing. I'm not. I will put the images of each view so it can be more clear. In the uploadView there are 2 (two) buttons, one for selecting the image and another to change the view (submit).

Comment: so you mean that the submit button is in uploadView

Comment: No no. (And I can't put the images I need more reputation) In IntroViewController I have 2 buttons that are unrelated to the problem. In UploadViewController I have 1 button that is to pick the image. In SwitchViewController I have 1 button and 1 ImageView, this button is both to change views and submit the image chosen in UploadViewController using the "select image" button declared in UploadViewController. I'm sorry if this is a bit confusing I hope this makes it clear.

Comment: @Joze you are trying to set the property of one of the objects present in one view by other view.

Comment: this is completely misleading. in gmail add my email robinson12gupta@gmail.com. may be we can talk there

Comment: Yes that is what I'm trying to do. I'm guessing that is not advisable... but what is the way to proceed then? If the methods I need to use are in UploadView and the view Switcher is SwitchView...